# How to determine the originator of an iMessage

Tags: ios

I got an iMessage, and it didn’t come from one of my contacts. I assigned it to one of my contacts, incorrectly.

How can i undo that? What I should have done is to let it create a new contact to associate with it.

Is there a way to access envelope information in the iMessage?

Help!

BTW, I am running most current iOS on iPhone 15.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can see which number or address a message was received by opening the contact card from within the Messages thread. Tap their name at the top of the thread, then tap "Info" to open their contact card. The number/address that sent you the message will be marked with "recent."

Secondly, you can also just open the contact card and edit it to reflect the addresses yo want associated with the card. Then, create a new contact card with the other addresses you wanted separated. You can do this in the Contacts app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
When you say “tap their name in the top of the thread”,  that shows the info associated with the contact that I accidentally attached to it. When the message arrived, there was no contact name at the top of the screen. There is no number marked “recent”. 

I have a message which has a contact of mine at the top of the message screen, and I can’t find ANY way to remove that association.   Is there an iOS tool to view the raw message header?